# Capistrano 3/Puma/Nginx/EC2 deosn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, puma

I've used this tutorial for deploying rails app to aws http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/

But when I try to open it in browser nginx says

```
2015/10/18 13:05:00 [crit] 11945#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/deploy/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/", host: "localhost"
```

What could be the problem? I've re-checked all the steps - seems like everything is correct.

Pro-guys, could you please review this tutorial and let me know why I have this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in my app. I have ElasticSearch usage in my models and elastic search wasn't installed. After installing it puma server started successfully